# how to evaluate inverse Laplace transform of $e^{- \sqrt{s}} $ using series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, laplace-transform, hyperbolic-functions

I tried to find an inverse Laplace transform by series as follows
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}}\right)(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} s^{\frac{k}{2}}\right)(t)$$
and by separate even orders with odd orders and get
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{(2k)!} s^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} s^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)(t)$$
then
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{(2k)!}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-k-\frac{1}{2}\right)t^{k+\frac{3}{2}}} $$
now its easy to evaluate the series
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right)+\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$
now I know the result is only $$\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$ So is the  Laplace transform of $\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)$ is zero ? and what if we use this way
$$ L^{-1}_s\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{s}\right)\right)=L^{-1}_s\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{(2k)!}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)!\Gamma(-k)t^{k+1}} $$
now gamma for negative integers is infinity So we can say (as wolfram say)
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(-k)}=0$$
finally
$$ f(t)=L^{-1}_s\left(e^{-\sqrt{s}}\right)(t)=\frac{t^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{4t}} $$
So is that using of series to get the result of inverse Laplace transform wrong ? or its true just here and how ?

**THIS QUESTION asked also on [MATHOVERFLOW](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462835/how-to-evaluate-inverse-laplace-transform-of-e-sqrts-using-series).**

Comment: Your answer is right. You may verify in M. Abramowitz and I. Stegun, Ch. 29 , ref. 29.3.82.

Comment: @Jean-LucBoulnois I know the answer and need just to learn about this way is it correct ? and why the inverse transform give us zero for $cosh$ function .